Problems configuring a custom dataset for torchtune and LLama 3.1
I am trying to use torchtune to finetune Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct, but I am not being very sucessfull. I put my data on the format of AlpacaInstruct as a jsonl file that is in the format:
{"instruction": "Text that describes a situation", "input": "", "output": "A classification of the text"}
{"instruction": "Another text that describes a situation", "input": "", "output": "A classification of the text"}

Maybe not the best way, but it is the closest I found of a Q/A on the examples at https://pytorch.org/torchtune/0.1/tutorials/datasets.html. So I thought it would be straight and forward, I added on my yaml the entry as follows:
  _component_: torchtune.datasets.instruct_dataset
  source: "json"
  data_files: "transformed_train_data_instruct.jsonl"
  template: torchtune.data.AlpacaInstructTemplate
  max_seq_len: 512
  train_on_input: True

however when I create the entry on the yaml I get the following message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/daniel/llm_fine_tuning/venv/bin/tune", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/daniel/llm_fine_tuning/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchtune/_cli/tune.py", line 49, in main
    parser.run(args)
  File "/home/daniel/llm_fine_tuning/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchtune/_cli/tune.py", line 43, in run
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/daniel/llm_fine_tuning/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchtune/_cli/run.py", line 179, in _run_cmd
    self._run_single_device(args)
  File "/home/daniel/llm_fine_tuning/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchtune/_cli/run.py", line 93, in _run_single_device
    runpy.run_path(str(args.recipe), run_name="__main__")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 289, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/daniel/llm_fine_tuning/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/recipes/full_finetune_single_device.py", line 524, in <module>
    sys.exit(recipe_main())
  File "/home/daniel/llm_fine_tuning/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchtune/config/_parse.py", line 50, in wrapper
    sys.exit(recipe_main(conf))
  File "/home/daniel/llm_fine_tuning/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/recipes/full_finetune_single_device.py", line 519, in recipe_main
    recipe.train()
  File "/home/daniel/llm_fine_tuning/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/recipes/full_finetune_single_device.py", line 425, in train
    for idx, batch in enumerate(self._dataloader):
  File "/home/daniel/llm_fine_tuning/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 630, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/daniel/llm_fine_tuning/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 673, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/home/daniel/llm_fine_tuning/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 52, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/daniel/llm_fine_tuning/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 52, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/daniel/llm_fine_tuning/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchtune/datasets/_instruct.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    sample = self._data[index]
  File "/home/daniel/llm_fine_tuning/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/dataset_dict.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(
KeyError: "Invalid key: 0. Please first select a split. For example: `my_dataset_dictionary['train'][0]`. Available splits: ['train']"

I am calling the code as:
tune run full_finetune_single_device --config my_8B_full_single_device.yaml      output_dir='./models/second_attempt_llama3_1'     compile=false

my my_8B_full_single_device.yaml is the following:
# Tokenizer
tokenizer:
  _component_: torchtune.models.llama3.llama3_tokenizer
  path: ./models/original/tokenizer.model

# Dataset
dataset:
  _component_: torchtune.datasets.instruct_dataset
  source: "json"
  data_files: "transformed_train_data_instruct.jsonl"
  template: torchtune.data.AlpacaInstructTemplate
  max_seq_len: 512
  train_on_input: True

# Model Arguments
model:
  _component_: torchtune.models.llama3.llama3_8b

checkpointer:
  _component_: torchtune.utils.FullModelMetaCheckpointer
  checkpoint_dir: ./models/original/
  checkpoint_files: [
    consolidated.00.pth
  ]
  recipe_checkpoint: null
  output_dir: ./models/
  model_type: LLAMA3
resume_from_checkpoint: False

# Fine-tuning arguments
seed: null
shuffle: True
batch_size: 2
epochs: 10

optimizer:
  _component_: bitsandbytes.optim.PagedAdamW8bit
  lr: 2e-5
loss:
  _component_: torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss
max_steps_per_epoch: null
gradient_accumulation_steps: 1
optimizer_in_bwd: True
compile: False

# Training environment
device: cuda

# Memory management
enable_activation_checkpointing: True

# Reduced precision
dtype: bf16

# Logging
metric_logger:
  _component_: torchtune.utils.metric_logging.DiskLogger
  log_dir: ${output_dir}
output_dir: ./models/full-llama3-finetune
log_every_n_steps: 1
log_peak_memory_stats: False

Any one has an idea of what am I doing wrong? Even better if you can point a good tutorial for torchtune, even using programming in python, it would be welcome.
The documentation at https://pytorch.org/torchtune is really good, but as they said themselves, the recepies are not for EVERYTHING. However, I am just trying to use a customized/personal dataset. Should not be THAT complex, right?
